# Awk script to provide sum of certain columns in another column basis on criteria

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

Need your help,
have one file where data is as shown below.
Data for both the below scenarios is present in only 1(single) file and want the expected output in same file only if possible

**Scenario 1:**

If the value in the first column `DocumentNo` is appearing once and 
 the second column `Line` has the value 10, then I would like to sum columns 3,4,5 and 6 (`Taxablevalue,IGSTAmount,CGSTAm` and `SGSTAmo`) and place/replace this value which we have summed in the eight column `Invoicevalue`:

*example data*:

```
DocumentNo|Line|Taxablevalue|IGSTAmount|CGSTAm|SGSTAmo|OthTa|InvoiceValue
262881894|10|10000|0|900|900||
```

**Senario 2:**

If we have multiple rows with identical values in the first column `DocumentNo` and unique value in the second column `LineN`, then I would like to sum all value of columns 3,4,5 and 6 (`Taxablevalue,IGSTAmount,CGSTAm` and `SGSTAmo`) and place/replace this value which we have summed in the eight column `Invoicevalue` of each line.

*example data*:

```
DocumentNo|LineN|Taxablevalue|IGSTAmo|CGSTAmo|SGSTAmou|OthTa|InvoValue
262881894|10|10000|0|900|900||              
262881894|20|15000|0|1350|1350||            
262881894|30|20000|0|1800|1800||
```

Expected output Scenario 1:

```
DocumentNo|Line|Taxablevalue|IGSTAmount|CGSTAm|SGSTAmo|OthTa|InvoiceValue
 262881894|10|10000|0|900|900||11800
```

Expected output Scenario 2:

> Invoice Value = 10000+15000+20000+0+0+0+900+1350+1800+900+1350+1800 =
>   53100

```
DocumentNo|LineN|Taxablevalue|IGSTAmo|CGSTAmo|SGSTAmou|OthTa|InvoValue
  262881894|10|10000|0|900|900||53100  
  262881894|20|15000|0|1350|1350||53100 
  262881894|30|20000|0|1800|1800||53100
```

Below is the code tried, but not able to figure out how to put added values in lastcolumn(InvoValue)

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$3;b[$1]+=$4;c[$1]+=$5;d[$1]+=$6;}
      END {for(i in a) { print " " a[i] " " b[i] " " c[i] " " d[i];}}' File
```

Below is output of code that I'm getting. Sadly it is not matching my expected output :

```
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Apologies for this..Sharing my code that i have tried in few minutes

Comment: What is the delimiter? Tab?

Comment: @Andriy Makukha..Delimiter is pipe "|"

Comment: @kvantour..have updated my question..please check

Comment: @as7951 Still a couple of small questions : is the input sorted in column 1? Can there appear identical lines cfr column 1 and column 2? In case 1, is it important that `$2` is 10?

Comment: @kvantour - hi, yes there can be indenticals rows in column1 but value/rows in column2(LineN) has to be unique for identical lines(column1).

Comment: @kvantour - hi, yes there can be indenticals rows in column1 but value/rows in column2(LineN) has to be unique for identical lines(column1). In $2 we can have any value..10 is not necessary...Also please note in column 3, column 4, 5 and 6...values can be decimal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in two passes.

On the first pass I would create a dictinary `s` that would hold the sum of columns 3, 4, 5 and 6 for any specific document number.

On the second pass I would replace the value in InvoValue column.

Here's an example input `data.txt`:

```
DocumentNo|LineN|Taxablevalue|IGSTAmo|CGSTAmo|SGSTAmou|OthTa|InvoValue
262881894|10|10000|0|900|900||
262881894|20|15000|0|1350|1350||
262881894|30|20000|0|1800|1800||
262881895|10|10000|0|900|900||
```

Here is the command:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" } NR == FNR { s[$1] += $3+$4+$5+$6; next } FNR!=1 { $8 = s[$1] } 1;' data.txt data.txt
```

Here is the output:

```
DocumentNo|LineN|Taxablevalue|IGSTAmo|CGSTAmo|SGSTAmou|OthTa|InvoValue
262881894|10|10000|0|900|900||53100
262881894|20|15000|0|1350|1350||53100
262881894|30|20000|0|1800|1800||53100
262881895|10|10000|0|900|900||11800
```

Note that I ignored column 2 altogether. You might need to modify my answer if you want to account for the LineN.

---

To ensure that all pairs (DocumentNo, LineN) are unique and occur only once, you could add this error detection:

```
if (met[$1 FS $2]) print "ERROR: " $1 " " $2; 
met[$1 FS $2] = 1;
```

So the updated command with error detection would be:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" } NR == FNR { if (met[$1 FS $2]) print "ERROR: " $1 " " $2; met[$1 FS $2] = 1; s[$1] += $3+$4+$5+$6; next } FNR!=1 { $8 = s[$1] } 1;' data.txt data.txt
```

Comment: Need to consider column2(lineN) as well, as for identical rows of column1 need to have unique rows in column2(LineN), and if not need to report error.

Comment: @as7951, I updated my answer with a variant of error reporting.